# Universal morphism in the first isomorphism theorem for groups.

Tags: category-theory, universal-property

I almost don't know anything about categories but I was reading about [universal morphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property#Formal_definition) and I wanted to see this in the context of the [first isomorphism theorem for groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_on_homomorphisms#Group_theoretic_version). What would the functor $F$ be in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $K$ be a normal subgroup of $G$, and consider the category $\mathcal C$ whose objects are the homomorphisms $\varphi:G\to H$ which vanish on $K$: $\varphi(K)=\{1_H\}$, and whose morphisms are commutative triangles (this is a full subcategory of the *comma category* $G/\mathcal{Grp}$).

Then define $F:\mathcal C\to\mathcal{Grp}$ by sending $\varphi:G\to H$ to $H$.

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand what "morphism are commutative triangles" means. Also how to compose such commutative triangles/morphisms?

Comment: If $\varphi:G\to H$ and $\varphi':G\to H'$ are objects, then a morphism $\varphi\to\varphi'$ will basically be a homomorphism $f:H\to H'$ which makes the arising triangle commutative, i.e. $\varphi=\varphi'\circ f$.

Comment: Okay, I see. So $F(\phi\to \phi ')=f$ and we have a universal morphism form $G$ to $F$ right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. ${{}}$